# Cron setup in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have tried to set up cron for magento 2 for receiving automated email. But it is not working. I didn't receive any emails

This is the command I used:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -c /home/foodstoc/public_html/bin/magento cron::run >/dev/null 2>&1

/usr/local/bin/php -c /home/foodstoc/public_html/update/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1

/usr/local/bin/php -c /home/foodstoc/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I also tried the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/foodstoc/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/foodstoc/public_html/bin/magento/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Note: when I run `cron:run` directly I receive email. But it is not getting automated.

Comment: Also tried the below also

Comment: Have you check cron log file?

Comment: Yes, there is no log file created, but the second one worked finally.. still cron runs every minute even I change the expression